# how to untoggle class on old card when new card is selected

Tags: javascript

Currently, when i click on a card, it changes the styling so that its border is white instead of grey, when i click on a new card, the previous card's border still remains white, how can i get the previous card to toggle again when new card is selected?

i know i just need some logic that will listen for another event on screen and will then remove class but i feel like there would be an easier way to do it...

```
var numberOfCards = document.querySelectorAll(".card").length;

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfCards; i++) {

  document.querySelectorAll(".card")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

    var currentCard = this.querySelector(".card .card-body .card-title").innerHTML;

    switch (currentCard) {
      case "Temperature":
        this.classList.toggle("card-clicked");
        break;

      case "pH":
        this.classList.toggle("card-clicked");
        break;

      case "Water Change":
        this.classList.toggle("card-clicked");
        break;

      case "Lighting":
        this.classList.toggle("card-clicked");
        break;

     default:
    }
  });
};
```

i tried to add in before the switch in an effort to remove all the card-clicked classes:

```
    switch (currentCard) {
      case "Temperature":
      case "pH":
      case "Water Change":
      case "Lightning":
        this.classList.remove("card-clicked");
        break;
    default:
    }
```

but i think it stops the second switch from running?

Comment: The event function you have defined will only fire on the card you have clicked on (when you click). You would need to remove the class from all others, then add the class to the current element. So basically you'll need to loop over the other cards within that function and remove their class. There's no real need for a switch here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) with [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) and a single click listener to exclusively toggle one card at a time:

```js
function toggleCard (card) {
  const isSelected = card.classList.contains('card-clicked');
  card.classList[isSelected ? 'remove' : 'add']('card-clicked');
  
  for (const c of document.querySelectorAll('.card')) {
    if (c !== card) c.classList.remove('card-clicked');
  }
}

document.querySelector('.cards').addEventListener('click', ev => {
  const card = ev.target.closest('.card');
  if (card) toggleCard(card);
});
```

```css
.cards {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.1rem;
}

.card {
  border: 4px solid;
  padding: 0.5rem
}

.card-clicked {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-title">Temperature</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-title">pH</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-title">Water Change</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-title">Lighting</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Matching your code style

```js
// store reference to all cards
var allCards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

// use length property from reference
for (var i = 0; i < allCards.length; i++) {
    // get card from allCards - no need to query again
    var card = allCards[i];

    card.addEventListener("click", function () {
        // get all cards again - in case they have changed
        var allCards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

        // loop over each one and remove class
        for(var i = 0; i < allCards.length;i++){
            allCards[i].classList.remove("card-clicked");
        }
        
        // add class back to this
        this.classList.add("card-clicked");
    });
};
```

If you have jQuery, this can be simpler:

```js
$(document)
    .on("click", ".card", function(){
        $(".card").removeClass("card-clicked");
        $(this).addClass("card-clicked");
    })
```